# Convert DynamoJson to something compatible with the Dynamo client

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java

I've got a big dump of DynamoJson e.g.

```
{"Item": {"id":{"N":"896"},  "name": {"S": "Tom"}}}
```

I want to parse this JSON and put it to my DynamoDB table...

I've tried:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
Item item = Item.fromJSON(BLOB);
```

But unfortunately its not smart enough to parse the DynamoDB Json format and doesn't deal with the inner types (S, N etc)... When I try to put I get errors like:

```
Type mismatch for key id expected: N actual: M
```

Related Questions:

[AWS DynamoDB on Android: Inserting JSON Directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813868/aws-dynamodb-on-android-inserting-json-directly)
This does not work for the DynamoJson format.

[Unmarshall DynamoDB JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535445/unmarshall-dynamodb-json)
This is exactly what I need but its in NodeJS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812278/converting-dynamodb-json-to-standard-json-with-java

Comment: I'd rather not use a custom converter from a robustness perspective.

Comment: What about the  ItemUtils answer.

Comment: Doesn't work... ItemUtils.toItem takes in an Map<String, AttributeValue> ... You first need a way to you convert the above DynamoDB Json to a Map<String, AttributeValue>... The answer in question constructs one by hand.

Comment: Are you using the AWS Java SDK V1? What version? 1.11.952?